# no response from laravel model []

Tags: php, laravel, model

I try to make model to communicate with rfid encoder in Laravel 5.4, the class work perfectly with php.
this is the Model RfidEncodage.php code :

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Response;

class RfidEncodage extends Model
{
private $socket;

public function __construct( $host, $port) {
    $this->socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    
    if ($socket === false)
        return "error";
    else {
            try{
                $result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port);
            }catch (\Exception $e) {
                return "==> <font color='red'>Connexion au Encodeur à échouer</font><br>".$e->getMessage()."";
            }
            if (Response::json($result) == true){
                return "==>  <font color='green'>Connexion au Encodeur Réussie . . .</font>";
            }else{
                return "==> <font color='red'>Connexion au Encodeur à échouer.</font>";
            }
        if ($result === false) {
            return "error " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
        } 
    }
}
public function read() {
    
    try{
        return socket_read($this->socket, 1024);
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
        return "==> <font color='red'>une erreur s'est produite lors du lecture!</font><br>".$e->getMessage()."";
    }
}
public function send($data) {
   
    try{
    socket_write($this->socket, $data, strlen($data.chr(0)));
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
        return "==> <font color='red'>une erreur s'est produite!</font><br>".$e->getMessage()."";
    }
}
public function close() {
   
    socket_close($this->socket);
    return "==>  <font color='green'>Connexion au Encodeur Fermer . . .</font>";
}
```

}

when t try to call it from the controller using :

```
 $open = new RfidEncodage("127.0.0.1",3306);
```

return [] ? need to return a message ok or error from the condition in RfidEncodage .

it's the correct way ?
how i can call read() and send() from the class??

Comment: what is `RfidEncodage`? seems an instance is trying to be created of it

Comment: RfidEncodage is my model laravel, itry to call from controller .

Comment: is this an Eloquent Model? as that constructor would be a really bad idea if it is ... if it is not what is this `index` method?

Comment: code updated ...

Comment: Also, you are trying to use the ```$this``` keyword in a [static](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) function. That is not going to work.

Comment: converted to public,

Answer (score 0):

A static member function can use a static variable inside it. You need to change your methods,First change

```
private static $socket;
```

use `self::$socket` everywhere instead of `$this->socket`
If you use $socket as static, then use it in contructor as `static::$socket`

See more about `self` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)